# When does it make sense to turn off the rasterization step?

Tags: c++, vulkan

In vulkan there is a struct which is required for pipeline creation, named `VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo`. In this struct there is a member named `rasterizerDiscardEnable`. If this member is set to `VK_TRUE` then all primitives are discarded before the rasterization step. This disables any output to the framebuffer.

I cannot think of a scenario where this might make any sense. In which cases could it be useful?

Comment: presumably to allow an extension to do something like opengl's transform feedback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would be for any case where you're executing the rendering pipeline solely for the side effects of the vertex processing stage(s). For example, you could use a GS to feed data into a buffer, which you later render from.

Now in many cases you could use a compute shader to do something similar. But you can't use a CS to efficiently implement tessellation; that's best done by the hardware tessellator. So if you want to capture data generated by tessellation (presumably because you'll be rendering with it multiple times), you have to use a rendering process.

Comment: To extend this a little with a real-world example:  Point tessellation voxelization (www.cs.columbia.edu/~fyun/gi12/paper100.pdf) is something I recently implemented and I use a graphics pass up to the tessellator and then use a geometry shader to write out to a 3D buffer.  From there you move to the compute shader to actually create the voxels.

Answer (score 7):

A useful side-effect (though not necessarily the intended use case) of this parameter is for benchmarking / determining the bottle-neck of your Vulkan application: If discarding all primitives before the rasterization stage (and thus before any fragment shaders are ever executed) does not improve your frame-rate then you can rule out that your application performance is fragment stage-bound.